# como acceder a un atributo url que esta dentro de un atributo avatar TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, img

estoy creando un proyecto web y tengo un error al ver el perfil del usuario, pues me carga todos los valores menos la foto del avatar, porque no me reconoce el url de la imagen. este es el error que me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria mi codigo

```
<div class="col-md-4 backgroundMega text-center text-white">
  <figure className='avatar avatar-profile'>
     <img className="rounded-circle img-fluid" src={user.avatar.url} alt={user.nombre} />
           </figure>
           <p>{user.nombre}</p>
           <p>{user.apellido} </p>
           <Link to={"/MyProfile/update"} id="edit_profile" className='btn btn-danger btn-block my-5 cafe' > EDIT PROFILE</Link>
</div>
```

Aqui les adjunto el codigo donde defino mi atributo avatar

```
const usuarioShema = new mongoose.Schema({
nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Por favor ingrese el nombre"],
    maxlength: [50, "El nombre no puede exceder de 120 caracteres"]
},
avatar: {
    public_id: 
    {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    url: 
    {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
},
```

adjunto tambien el controlador de la clase usuario
exports.registroUsuario = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
const { nombre, apellido, email, password, genero } = req.body;

```
const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
    folder: "avatars",
    width:240,
    crop:"scale"
})

const user = await User.create({
    nombre,
    apellido,
    email,
    password,
    avatar:{
        public_id:result.public_id,
        url:result.secure_url
    },
    genero
})
```

Les agradeceria mucho si me pueden ayudar, cuando quito el user.avatar.url y lo dejo solo user.avatar me sale todo menos la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posiblemente el error venga porque la obencion de los datos del usuario es asíncrona y al principio no tienes datos. Si no veo todo el código no puedo estar seguro pero si modificas el atributo src con esto debería funcionar `src={user?.avatar?.url}`

Answer (score 0):

esto te sucede no porque no puedas acceder dentro del objeto, sino que React renderiza primero la pagina sin datos en user, por lo que user es null.

Entonces intentas hacer algo como user.null.url, null no es un objeto que tenga url, por eso el error jeje.

Despues que obtiene user ya vuelve a renderizar con los datos.

Tienes que hacer que tu codigo no se rompa al renderizar por primera vez.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
        setNombre(user.nombre);
        setApellido(user.apellido);
        setGenero(user.genero)
        setAvatarPreview(user.avatar?.url)
    }
},[user]);
```

Agregando el signo de interrogacion evitas que tu codigo se rompa, si avatar es null va a ignorar .url

A pesar de que tengas la validacion de su user existe, probableme tu objeto user sea un objeto vacio al inicio {} y por eso da true y entra y falla.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos evitar realizar respuestas duplicadas. Revisar [answer] y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido , saludos.